# How can I cycle through sprites when the player touches some UI element?

Tags: unity, sprites, touch

```
    if(Input.GetKey("y")){
        gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = Characters[0];

    }
    if(Input.GetKey("u")){
        gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = Characters[1];
    }
    if(Input.GetKey("i")){
        gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = Characters[2];
    }
```

This is my current script, which changes character at keypress Y, U, and I. However as I am developing for touch, I want them to change when a box at the screen is pressed (Left one):

[image]

How can I proceed with this? Can I set the sprites to numbers, and let's say at button press, it adds +1, and that changes the sprite? And if so, how does the last one work to get it back at 0?
Appriciate all answers. :)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
selected_character++;
if (selected_character >= num_characters)
{
    selected_character = 0;
}
```

and you can select the sprite by

```
gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = Characters[selected_character];
```

You also have to declare a new class member to make the code above work:

```
int selected_character = 0;
```